# Why can I not raise certain skills?

Tags: mass-effect

I recently got Mass Effect 1 and started playing. I am an Infiltrator, so I primarily use snipers. (Probably not the easiest to start with).

When I level up, the 'sniper rifle' level of skill points is inaccessible to me, as well as a few others: fitness being one.

Is there a reason for this? What sort of level can I start putting points into it?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you're an Infiltrator then Sniper Rifles and Fitness are both unlockable talent for your class, you will get access to them, but not at the start of the game.

---

To unlock any locked talent, you need to first place a certain number of points in to another talent first.

For the Infiltrator class these are:

- **Sniper Rifles** is unlocked when your **Pistol** talent is at **5**.
- **Fitness** is unlocked when your **Tactical Armour** talent is at **6**.
- **Dampening** is unlocked when your **Electronics** talent is at **4**.
- **First Aid** is unlocked when your **Decryption** talent is at **7**.

As per the [Mass Effect Wikia](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Infiltrator).

Comment: A minute earlier, but beaten by bullet points a extra information. Well played sir.

Answer (score 6):

Certain talents are unlocked by bringing a predecessor talent up to a certain level.

For Infiltrators, your Pistols skill must be at 5 to unlock Sniper Rifles and your Tactical Armor skill must be at 6 to unlock Fitness.

Please see the [Infiltrator wiki article](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Infiltrator) for more information.